# Getting error with findBlobs() in simpleCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, blob, simplecv, blobs

I am converting an OpenCV image to SimpleCV via simple Image(opencv_image) call and using Image.findBlobs() to get the blob. However, I can not  get the bounding box using Blobs.getBoundingBox() as I get the error :

blobs.draw()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'

fgmask is the foreground mask I have received after background subtraction.

Here is my code:

```
simplecvimg = Image(fgmask, cv2image=True)
blobs = simplecvimg.findBlobs()
blobs.draw()
simplecvimg.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `findBlobs` doesn't find any blobs, or if there's some problem with input image, it returns `None`. And hence the error. So you might want to add a check if blobs is None or not.

```
if blobs is not None:
    blobs.draw()
simplecvimg.show()
```

Also, try using some other image to see if the error persists.

Comment: findBlobs is actually returning None. Why is that so? I can see white blobs in simplecvimg!